# Missing permissions required by FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates

Tags: java

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        if (fusedLocationProviderClient != null)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission
                        (Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
            }


        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
```

Comment: Missing permissions required by FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the required permissions in your `AndoidManifest.xml` file.

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

or

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```